# how to move a group of skspritenodes together

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to move a group of skspritenodes together. I already put them under the same name. But I want to shift them as a group sideways to the left. How can I do that? Each node has a different x and y position, so what I can do to change the position of the nodes so that they all stay together but shift sideways?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

you can add x or y in position to all nodes by searching

```
self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//NodeName", using: { node, stop in
        if let node = node as? SKSpriteNode {
            //move
         }
})
```

[image]

or add them to a vector:

```
class TTESTGameScene: SKScene {
    
    var allBoxes: [SKSpriteNode] = []
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
        view.allowsTransparency = true
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.alpha = 1.0
        view.isOpaque = true
        view.backgroundColor = SKColor.clear.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
        
        let upButton = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.maxY - 40, width: 66, height: 33), cornerRadius: 20)
        upButton.fillColor = .yellow
        upButton.name = "upButton"
        addChild(upButton)
        let downButton = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 80, y: view.frame.maxY - 40, width: 66, height: 33), cornerRadius: 20)
        downButton.fillColor = .orange
        downButton.name = "downButton"
        addChild(downButton)
        let addBox = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 200, y: view.frame.maxY - 40, width: 66, height: 33), cornerRadius: 20)
        addBox.fillColor = .red
        addBox.name = "addBox"
        addChild(addBox)
    }

    func addBox() {
        let box = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
        box.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat.random(in: 10..<200), y: CGFloat.random(in: 10..<200))
        box.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
        box.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        addChild(box)
        allBoxes.append(box)
    }
    
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
        
        let sceneTouchPoint = self.convertPoint(fromView: location)
        let touchedNode = self.atPoint(sceneTouchPoint)
        print(touchedNode.name)
        if touchedNode.name == "upButton" {
            allBoxes.forEach() { box in
                box.position.addY(10)
            }
        }
        else if touchedNode.name == "downButton" {
            allBoxes.forEach() { box in
                box.position.addY(-10)
            }
        }
        else if touchedNode.name == "addBox" {
            addBox()
        }
            
        
    }
}
extension CGPoint {
    public mutating func addX(_ x:CGFloat){
        let p:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.x + x, y: self.y)
        self = p
    }
    public mutating func addY(_ y:CGFloat){
        let p:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.x, y: self.y + y)
        self = p
    }
}
// A sample SwiftUI creating a GameScene and sizing it
// at 300x400 points
struct TTESTContentView: View {
    var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = TTESTGameScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 400)
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        return scene
    }

    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: scene)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
            //.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
struct ContentViewTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TTESTContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either make the 2nd and subsequent nodes children of the first node, or make them all children of some possible invisible node.

Then moving the parent will move all the children too. You may have to adjust the way you create the nodes with regards to their X and Y positions, as those are relative to the parent.